# types may not be defined in 'sizeof' expressions in module_param

Tags: sizeof, kernel-module

I am writing a bluetooth driver for debian based linux. I have used `module_param` to send command line argument to a module. It takes 3 arguments. First is the variable to store the argument value, second is the type of the argument and third is the permission.

my code looks like this....

```
#include <linux/module.h>

bool x =1;
module_param(x,bool,0000);
```

one more thing is I am compiling the module using **g++** and I know people write module in **C**.

the error I am getting is like this.

**test.cc:10:error: types may not be defined in 'sizeof' expressions**

Please post if you have an answer for it.

Comment: Please go through this link http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-gnulib@gnu.org/msg01306.html. Hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with verfiy.h file with c++. They have fixed it in latest g++ compiler (g++ 3.2.2 and 4.0.1), try downloading the latest g++ and compile. Please go through this link http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-gnulib@gnu.org/msg01306.html. Hope this answers your question :-).